# Concatenate all values up to current date

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

Say we have a table of products and the year in which each product was sold. Using Qliksense, I would like to add a column that concatenates all products that were sold up to the respective year.

| year | product |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | A |
| 2021 | B |
| 2022 | C |

Desired outcome would be:

| year | product | concatenate_products |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | A | A |
| 2021 | B | A-B |
| 2022 | C | A-B-C |

See below for what I tried so far. It gave error "invalid expression".

```
Load
   *,
   if(RowNo()=1, 'A', Concat(distinct Peek(concatenate_products), product)) as concatenate_products
resident Table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier to create the new field in separate table and then join to the source table:

```
Load * Inline [
year, product
2020, A
2021, B
2022, C
];

NoConcatenate

// get list of only distinct year <-> product values
DistinctValues:
Load
 distinct
  year,
  product
Resident
  RawData
;


// calculate the combined product field
// and join back to the source table.
// the join will be performed on 2 fields: year and product
join (RawData)

Load
  *,
   if(RowNo() = 1, product, peek(concatenate_products) & '-' & product) as concatenate_products
Resident
  DistinctValues
;

Drop Table DistinctValues;
```

Result table:

[image: result table]